# I2C devices on docker container

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am running a docker container on Raspberry Pi 3 and I am trying to read from an I2C device from the container. When I use `i2cdetect` inside docker I can see the devices. The run option I use is `sudo docker run --device /dev/i2c-1  --name <name> <image>`, but when I try to read from the I2C device all CRC checks fail as if the file `/dev/i2c-1` didn't mount correctly. It looks like the directory has just been copied on run and did not bind. Has anyone else experienced this?

I have also tried the `--privileged` option and binding the folder `-v -v /dev:/dev`.

I can't use `i2cget` to test the device because it uses 16bit addressing

I use the wiringPi library for C https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi.

On run I get these messages:

```
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:103:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:104:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:105:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:106:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
_apt:x:104:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

Output from `i2cdetect -y 1` in docker:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: You might like to ask that on the dedicated [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site instead.

Comment: How do you read from the i2 device?

Comment: I use the wiringPi library for C [https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi)